# Show different number of products in category page

Tags: category, product-collection, magento-1, pagination, collection-limit

I am trying to show different number of products in category but it is only working on page 1. I want to show 22 products on page1 and rest all the pages 20 products per page. I managed to change by setPageSize in first page and it is working well, but rest all the pages I am unable to get products limit to 20 per page.

```
Page 1...22 products //works well
Page 2...20 products //doesn't work..shows from 21 to 40
Page 3...20 products //doesn't work..shows from 41 to 60
```

Here is how I am doing:

```
$currentPage = (int) Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('p');
if ($currentPage==0 || $currentPage==1){
    $productCollection->clear();
    $productCollection->setCurPage($currentPage)->setPageSize(22); //works..
} else {
        $productCollection->clear(); 
        $productCollection->getSelect()->limit(20,22); //doesn't work
}
```

Any idea how can I solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `LIMIT` is calculated based on "page size" and "current page" immediately before the collection is loaded. See [Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract::_loadEntities()](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/cf43f51aab6125f03a0083df1c00ac0f34b86c86/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php#L1033-L1035):

```
public function _loadEntities($printQuery = false, $logQuery = false)
{
    if ($this->_pageSize) {
        $this->getSelect()->limitPage($this->getCurPage(), $this->_pageSize);
    }
```

You can prevent this by setting `_pageSize` to 0:

```
$productCollection->setPageSize(0);
$productCollection->getSelect()->limit(20,22);
```

Besides that, resetting the already loaded collection to load it again is not a good idea.

You can write an observer for `catalog_product_collection_load_before` to manipulate the limit right before the collection is loaded:

```
public function setProductPaging(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) 
{
    $collection = $observer->getCollection();
    if ($collection->getCurPage() == 1) {
        $collection->setPageSize(22);
    } else {
        $productCollection->setPageSize(0);
        $productCollection->getSelect()->limit(20, 22 + 20 * ($collection->getCurPage() - 2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will check this and let you know if it works. Looks like it should work though.

Comment: It does seem to work but pagination is not correct. If there are 21 products then instead of showing 1 page it shows 2. Any idea?

Comment: OK this is going to be tricky because the number of pages is calculated by number of items divided by page size. You will need to manipulate this calculation in the toolbar block somehow

Comment: I figured it out we can set the product limit on cat page here `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->setLimitPage(22);` before toolbar is called. Thanks!

Comment: I have used this event `catalog_block_product_list_collection`